# Populate data in dropdown from google datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, google-cloud-datastore, gwtp

Hi I have gwtp google appengine application which has a search field which is a dropdown. The data in the dropdown has to come from the datastore. But my problem is this data in the datastore is not unique and it is more than 10000 records. Please suggest a way to populate data into dropdown. (Java version)
FYI: i am using

- GWTP
- google appengine in Java

Answer (score 1):

a dropdown with 10000 items seems isn't quite user friendly? Imagine the difficulty you have to scroll though 10000 items to look for the item you want (even though it is sorted).

can you do it with auto complete instead?

Comment: auto complete is fine but the data in datastore may have duplicate. Can you provide me an example